# Word Interop Header & Footer with Multiple Fields

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to work out how to update\change the fields on a template.  So far, every piece of good intel I've found has caused the current header or footer to be completely overwritten.  It's pretty obvious.  The problem is that I can't find how to specifically modify certain fields in the footer rather than the entire footer.

```
        // Set headers
        foreach (Word.Section section in doc.Sections)
        {
            Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
            headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
        }

        // Set footers
        foreach (Word.Section wordSection in doc.Sections)
        {
            Word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            footerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
            footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkRed;
            footerRange.Font.Size = 20;
            footerRange.Text = "Confidential";
        }
```

In this code, I am trying to get the word "Confidential" to over write the middle field.  Currently the middle field is blank.  The left and right fields are the page number and the date respectively.  Once I run the code, it all gets replaced with the "Confidential" code.  It also completely removes the shape that's placed as a background color accent to the footer.

[image]
Tab stops at 3.25" and 6.5"

[image]

How do I modify existing fields?  Will the shape be deleted this way?

**update:**
The following code is as far as I've gotten before I felt like I was going in circles.  It all seems very sequential as if you're physically typing\editing the document.  Ick.  Either way, this is close.  The formatting is ignored for some reason though, and I can't get it to apply it to only the center text.  Also, if I uncomment the date field line, the entire footer gets erased.

```
        // Set footers
        foreach (Word.Section wordSection in doc.Sections)
        {
            Word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            footerRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
            footerRange.Paragraphs.TabStops.Add(wordApp.InchesToPoints(3.25F), Word.WdTabAlignment.wdAlignTabCenter);
            footerRange.Paragraphs.TabStops.Add(wordApp.InchesToPoints(6.5F), Word.WdTabAlignment.wdAlignTabRight);

            footerRange.Fields.Add(footerRange, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage, "\t", true);
            footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkRed;
            footerRange.Font.Size = 20;
            footerRange.Text = "\tCONFIDENTIAL\t";
            footerRange.InsertBefore("01-DEC-18");
            //footerRange.Fields.Add(footerRange, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldDate);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific about how to identify "the middle field"? If this is a "standard" Footer, it uses TAB characters and tab stops to align content. If this is the case here, turning on the display of non-printing characters can help us see that in the screen captures. Without identifying information it's only possible to *guess* what might work...

Comment: I also remind you that according to site policy a question should contain only ONE query, not more. Please post a *separate* question for a second query. And include all details, such as *where* the date/time field(s) are located in the document...

Comment: @CindyMeister I updated the image.

Comment: Thanks for the updated information - which came during the middle of my night. My approach posted below.

Answer (score 1):

The following substitutes "Confidential" with the specified formatting for what is currently in the second section of each primary Footer range in the document. ("second section" means the content between the first and second tab stops).

The key is finding the two tab stops' `Range` locations and setting the target `Range` for the content at one character folowing the first tab stop and one character preceding the second tab stop.

```
Word.Range ftr = null;
Word.Paragraph para = null;
Word.Range paraRng = null;
Word.Range tStop1 = null;
Word.Range tStop2 = null;
int nrTabs;

foreach (Word.Section sec in doc.Sections)
        {
    ftr = sec.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    para = ftr.Paragraphs[1];
    nrTabs = para.TabStops.Count;
    if (nrTabs == 2)
    {
        paraRng = para.Range;
        tStop1 = paraRng.Duplicate;
        tStop1.Find.Execute("^t", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
            missing, missing, Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop);
        tStop1.MoveStart(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1); //put it after the tab character
        tStop2 = tStop1.Duplicate;
        tStop2.Find.Execute("^t", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
            missing, missing, Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop);
        tStop2.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1); //put it before the tab character
        tStop1.End = tStop2.End;
        tStop1.Text = "Confidential";
        tStop1.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkRed;
        tStop1.Font.Size = 20f;
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails the if comparison.  nrTabs ends up being 13.  It's interesting because the template currently contains NO tab stops - at least not until I add them programatically.  I wish I knew this library better.  How can I quickly determine exactly what the software thinks ftr.Paragraph[1] is?  Changing the if evaluation to 13 - the rest of the statement changes the footer.  The phrase "Confidential" ends up being on the far left of the footer.  That's the only thing there.  Do you have working datefield code?

Comment: Mmm. This approach bases on the assumption that the default Footer style is being used. I have trouble imagining WHY (and how) a Footer would contain 13 tab stops. In your place (and not knowing any more than I do) I'd open that template in Word and inspect it very carefully. Any solution needs to base on the document(s) it runs on, which only the person asking can analyse. To find out what ftr.Paragraphs[1] is I'd do ftr.Paragraphs[1].Range.Select(); and have the code end (comment out everything else) so that I can *see* it. Or I'd test my basic concept in VBA (more comfortable and forgiving)

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "working datefield code" but do think it would be better for that to be a different question as it's not directly related to "...I can't find how to specifically modify certain fields in the footer rather than the entire footer."

Comment: If this is a template *you* are setting up I'd put a bookmark in the positions that need to be changed by the code. My assumption was that this could be "any" document so a more generic approach would be required.

Answer (score 0):

I just went ahead and did it manually to get the best results.

```
        string tab = "\t";
        string note = "Confidential";
        string dt = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("d");
        int pg = 0;
        // Set footers
        foreach (Word.Section wordSection in doc.Sections)
        {
            pg += 1;
            Word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            footerRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
            footerRange.Paragraphs.TabStops.Add(wordApp.InchesToPoints(3.25F), Word.WdTabAlignment.wdAlignTabCenter);
            footerRange.Paragraphs.TabStops.Add(wordApp.InchesToPoints(6.5F), Word.WdTabAlignment.wdAlignTabRight);
            string footerString = $"pg. {pg.ToString()}{tab}{note}{tab}{dt}";
            footerRange.Text = footerString;
        }
```

Comment: Word does have a Footer style that is automatically applied to all Footers in a document. That style contains two tab stops. If those are not what you want/need it's "better" to change the style definition than add the tab stops directly to the Footer Range. For one thing, you're likely to end up with four instead of two tab stops. For another, the code will be more efficient since the change need be applied only once (to the style) rather than separately for each section. AND, if it ever needs changing (again), it can be done in once place (the style) rather than changing (again) all sections

Comment: Also, in this code the page number is going to be static on all pages rather than a Word field that will increment automatically. The above code only makes sense if each page is one section and only one page in length...

Comment: @CindyMeister That IS what I want, and is essentially what I inefficiently recreated.  Believe me, I was trying to avoid doing it manually at all costs, and it cost me the better part of a day.  I wanted to do this the Word automated way, but I just couldn't find the resources to get me there.  I'll happily work with the code you posted to see what I come up with.